# How to succinctly name all elements of several lists the same when the lists are nested in an R list?

Tags: r

Sometimes I come across this instance in R:

```
L <- list()
L[[1]] <- list()
L[[2]] <- list()
L[[1]][[1]] <- 1
L[[1]][[2]] <- 2
L[[2]][[1]] <- 1
L[[2]][[2]] <- 2
```

Then I want to name all elements of the nested lists in `L` the same. I usually do something like this:

```
L <- lapply(L, function(x){names(x) <- c("One", "Two"); x})
```

However, this looks kind of awful and I'm sure there has to be a better way. Does anyone know a more elegant way?

Comment: Don't forget that `"names<-"` is also a function, meaning you can also do: `lapply(L, "names<-", c("One", "Two"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing two step process, we can use the wrapper `setNames`

```
L <- lapply(L, setNames, c("One", "Two"))
```

---

Or similar option with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(L, set_names, c("One", "Two"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `Map` (but not as concise as `lapply` by [@akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65525858/12158757))

```
> Map(setNames, L, rep(list(c("One", "Two")), length(L)))
[[1]]
[[1]]$One
[1] 1

[[1]]$Two
[1] 2


[[2]]
[[2]]$One
[1] 1

[[2]]$Two
[1] 2
```